# Navigation bar located on image slider not working when I am adding text to a image. How can I fix it?

Tags: html

In my text code, the below CSS style is not working. What is missing?

```
.text2 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    right:200px;
    padding-left: 200px;
    padding-right: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom:20%;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 6000px;
    font-size: 300px;
    left: 20px;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try make sure that the parent element has the `position: relative` , also make sure that the background has different color than `white` as the text color is white.

Comment: also the padding-top has quite big value

Comment: Thanks @mahmed nabil,I changed padding top value and it helped. 